# Import CSVReader in java

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I'm trying to import the CSVReader into my Java project, but when I tried to build the project, it says that 'The import au cannot be resolved'.

I've added the opencsv-3.3.jar into my build path, and have imported the following in my source code.

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategy;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
```

What else could be missing or wrong that causes this issue?

Comment: That jar just uses 'com.opencsv' as the package name.

Comment: you are not importing it correctly or its not in class path.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Didn't realized that they are using different package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the rigth Jar. For example you can take it from here [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/au.com.bytecode/opencsv/2.4)

This contains the packages `au.com.bytecode.opencsv` and the repository is located at https://github.com/EmergentOrder/opencsv which is a fork of https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/

The project on https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/ provide the packages `com.opencsv`

Depending which project you want to use. Maybe changing the package name in the import statement would fix it (when opencsv-3.3.jar is the Jar you need to use).

Comment: Thank you. I've found the difference and it is working now. Originally thought that the opencsv-3.3.jar is just a newer version as compared to opencsv-2.4.jar

Comment: For reading a CSV file without adding a jar you can look here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/